# How can I find the different value in array by php?

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I have cafeid=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
and checkid= (1,3,5)

How can I show the output only (2,4,6,7)?

Answer (score 6):

By using

- [array_diff](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) — Computes the difference of arrays

Example:

```
$cafeid  = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$checkid = array(1,3,5);
print_r( array_diff($cafeid, $checkid) );
```

will give:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/array_diff)** function to return the values that are present in the first array, and not in the second one.

As an example, in your situation, this portion of code :

```
$cafeid = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$checkid = array(1,3,5);
var_dump(array_diff($cafeid, $checkid));
```

will get you this kind of output :

```
array
  1 => int 2
  3 => int 4
  5 => int 6
  6 => int 7
```

As an advice : there are a lot of useful function that allow one to manipulate arrays and work with them ; you should take a quick look at the list of those functions : **[Array Functions][2]**.

I'm pretty sure this'll be useful one day or another ;-)

Comment: Damn ^^ There should be a badge for being faster ^^ *(I would sometimes get it -- but not every time, it seems ^^ )*